# compare date today

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, drop-down-menu

I am new to MVC.  I want to use the dropdownlist to show `onchange`, once the dropdownlist changes anything, the view page will show the data from database

```
@Html.DropDownList("id", new SelectList(
    new[] { "Today", "Yesterday", "Older" }), " [Show By] ", 
    new { id = "history", onchange = "this.form.submit();" 
})

public ActionResult History(int id)
{

}
```

How do I type this statement? I am using lightspeed > LINQ. My database entity name is "visitors" and my field name is "timeout". My database store inside is datetime default which is formatted as following "5/9/2011 4:48:03 PM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use [DateTime Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx) or [CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ata5aya.aspx) methods in your Linq Expression.
For example, if timeout field is DateTime(not nullable type) you can write:

```
dbContext.visitors.Where(v=>v.timeout.CompareTo(DateTime.Now)==0); //today
dbContext.visitors.Where(v=>v.timeout.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))==0); //yesterday
dbContext.visitors.Where(v=>v.timeout.Compare(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))<0); //older
```